# How to configure Sequel to work with PgBouncer? How to make sure Sequel doesn't use prepared statements?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel, pgbouncer

According to Heroku docs all that you're supposed to do is to disable prepared statements ([LINK](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#limit-connections-with-pgbouncer)) - hence the two questions in the title, because it is my understanding it is one and the same issue,

and with Rails you'd do something like [THIS](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer#disable-prepared-statements)

but I'm having a hard time understanding explicitly how it works in Sequel - if Sequel even uses prepared statements by default - or if it's dependent on the driver used, and if it uses them because it's configured that way - how to tell it's using them,

and it seems like I'll have to "test in production" (on a small customer set) because of current project constraints - so I'd like to know as much as possible about how to set up Sequel and what the possible ramifications could be.

As far as I can tell - the only thing that I need to do is make sure that Sequel doesn't use prepared statements, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like with sequel, prepared statements are created explicitly by the developer. You use [prepare](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/prepared_statements_rdoc.html#label-Prepared+Statements) to create the prepared statement, and then later `call` with the values you want to use